# Set up Branch preview deployments with gitlab-ci.yml for static website deployed on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-static-web-app, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a static web app deployed on an azure app service. This is my gitlab-ci.yml for CI/CD on production -

```
variables:
  API_TOKEN: $DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN
  APP_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR'
  REACT_APP_ENV: $REACT_APP_ENV
  REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID: $REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID
  REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY: $REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/static-web-apps/azure-static-web-apps-deploy
  script:
    - echo "App deployed successfully."
```

This works great for deploying when I merge to master.

Now I want to update this yml to also do deployments and create preview urls when I open a PR on a branch branched-off master.

How do I update this yml to do that?

Tried -

```
variables:
  API_TOKEN: $DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN
  APP_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR'
  REACT_APP_ENV: $REACT_APP_ENV
  REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID: $REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID
  REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY: $REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y nodejs npm
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
    - az --version
    - DEPLOYED_URL=$(az staticwebapp show --resource-group providentiainterviewbackend --name aihyr-prod-frontend --query "defaultHostname" -o tsv)
    - echo $DEPLOYED_URL
  environment: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
```

It says I need to add az login. But wouldnt I need to give credentials for az login? Is there a better and easier way of doing this?

Comment: Hi @Khyati Thakur Welcome to SO, You can utilize GitLab's CI/CD environment variables along with the Azure Static Web Apps CLI to generate preview URLs for branches derived from the master branch, eliminating the need for repeated logins. and use **`az login`** with service principal authentication. Make sure The `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`, `AZURE_TENANT_ID`, and `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` environment variables are set in your GitLab CI/CD settings. These values are associated with your Azure service principal.

Comment: deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y nodejs npm
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    # Authenticate with Azure using the provided service principal
    - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    # Set Azure subscription
    - az account set --subscription $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    # Get the URL for the production deployment

Comment: @SiddheshDesai - thank you for your response. I am trying to do exactly as you said in your comments but the pipeline is throwing invalid Tenant ID error for me now. I am using the correct tenant id that I am getting from azure though. I have been stuck on this for a whole day now. Is there no easy way to set up preview environments for pull-requests or branches on azure static web apps using gitlab?

Comment: throwing invalid Tenant ID error for me now. I am using the correct tenant id that I am getting from azure though. >> Are you using Tenant Id mentioned here- https://i.imgur.com/NAvum1n.png Also make sure the Azure AD tenant you are using is connected to the same Subscription that has your Web app

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize GitLab's CI/CD environment variables along with the Azure Static Web Apps CLI to generate preview URLs for branches derived from the master branch, eliminating the need for repeated logins. and use  **`az login`**  with service principal authentication. Make sure The  `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`,  `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`,  `AZURE_TENANT_ID`, and  `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`  environment variables are set in your GitLab CI/CD settings. These values are associated with your Azure service principal.

```yaml
variables:
  API_TOKEN: $DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN
  APP_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR'
  REACT_APP_ENV: $REACT_APP_ENV
  REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID: $REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID
  REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY: $REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY
  AZURE_CLIENT_ID:  c0c952e9-5254-45b5-b838-6d26a31435cb
 AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET:  snG8Q~c13XI06mOPVrqDWZaSTb6oFCl-LUD_Aavp
 AZURE_TENANT_ID:  83331f4e-7f45-4ce4-99ed-af9038592395
 AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME:  siliconfunc653

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y nodejs npm
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    # Authenticate with Azure using the provided service principal
    - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    # Set Azure subscription
    - az account set --subscription $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    # Get the URL for the production deployment
    - DEPLOYED_URL=$(az staticwebapp show --resource-group providentiainterviewbackend --name aihyr-prod-frontend --query "defaultHostname" -o tsv)
    - echo "Production deployment URL: $DEPLOYED_URL"
    # Create preview URL for the branch
    - PREVIEW_URL=$(az staticwebapp hostname create --resource-group providentiainterviewbackend --name aihyr-prod-frontend --hostname $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG --branch $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --query "hostname" -o tsv)
    - echo "Preview deployment URL: $PREVIEW_URL"
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    url: $PREVIEW_URL
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
```

> throwing invalid Tenant ID error for me now. I am using the correct tenant id that I am getting from azure though

In order to resolve this error:-

Make sure the **`Tenant ID`** variable you are using if correct and from this option below:-

[image]

It should be the Tenant Id of the Directory connected to your Azure subscription.

[image]

Make sure you are logged into correct directory or Switch to the correct directory that has your subscription which contains the  Web app.

[image]